# Нужны советы по задаче, скажите идею или алгоритм

Tags: c++, алгоритм

Дан массив A[n]. Дано число T . Нужно посчитать кол-во пар, где A[i]+A[j]=T . Подскажите, пожалуйста, какую-нибудь идею для эффективного решения.

Comment: Ну, навскидку - отсортировать массив и идти с двух концов... Отдельно обрабатывать, если идут несколько одинаковых значений подряд. Получается сложность сортировки + O(n)

Comment: Отсортировать, сохранив сведения об исходном индексе. Для каждого элемента искать пару методом половинного деления. Как только пара имеет меньший текущий индекс - стоп.

Comment: полный перебор — будет O(n*log(n))... если нет ни каких доп. условий, то быстрее ни как..

Comment: @Harry, сортировка O(n*log(n)) всё равно будет...

Comment: @Fat-Zer Ну а вдруг можно будет сортировать подсчетом, например? :)

Comment: Ребят, то есть мне просто отсортировать, а потом ?

Comment: @Harry, если подсчётом можно было бы, то тут и сортировка собственно не нужна...

Comment: @Альтаир отсортируй, напиши на листочке отсортированный массив, и иди двумя указателями с разных концов отсортированного массива навстречу друг другу. На каждом шаге считаешь сумму элментов, на которые указывают указатели, она будет либо меньше чем T, либо равна T, либо больше T (три ситуации, `<`, `==`, `>`. Ну так вот, нарисуй на листочке, и подумай какой из указателей двигать в какой ситуации. Так как массив отсортирован, то двигая один из указателей ты знаешь что станет с суммой на следующем шаге

Comment: Вообще, тут решение за O(n) без сортировки есть. Задачи по теме: [1](https://leetcode.com/problems/two-sum/), [2](https://leetcode.com/problems/3sum/), [3](https://leetcode.com/problems/container-with-most-water/)

Comment: @vt-egorov разве что с хеш-таблицей, тогда в среднем можно за O(n), но скорее всего с достаточно большим коэффициентом

Comment: @extrn и тем не менее O(n) будет

Comment: @vt-egorov да это понятно, это вообще первая мысль которая пришла в голову. Я хотел предложить в качестве альтернативы сортировке подсчетом :)

Comment: я, кстати, в прошлый раз глупость сказал — у полного перебора сложность квадратичная... сотру попозже...

Comment: Кстати, какие-то ограничения на размер массива + величина чисел в массиве есть? Допускаются ли одинаковые значения в массиве? это все существенно влияет на выбор метода решения...

Comment: Все элменты различны

Comment: using namespace std;
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
 int n, t;
 cin >> n >> t;
 int* a;
 a = new int[n];
 for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)cin >> a[i];
 //sorting
 for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
  int j = i;
  while (j > 0 && a[j] < a[j - 1]) {
   int t = a[j];
   a[j] = a[j - 1];
   a[j - 1] = t;
   j--;
  }
 }
 
 int k = 0;
 int i = 0, j = n-1;
 while (i < j) {
  if (a[i] + a[j] == t) { i++; j--; k++; }
  else
   if (a[i] + a[j] < t)  i++;
   else
    j--;
 }
 cout << k;
}   проверьте , пожалуйста

Comment: Задолбали критикой, я всего лишь хотел посмотреть, что будет :) Вобщем, чтоб не было лишних дискуссий, свой ответ удаляю.

Comment: В чём проблема загуглить? Это очень известная задача https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/count-pairs-with-given-sum/ https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/print-all-pairs-with-given-sum/ https://www.techiedelight.com/find-pair-with-given-sum-array/

Answer (score 0):

```
const int n = 10;
int mass[n];
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    mass[i]= rand() % 10;
    std::cout << mass[i] << " ";
}
std::cout << std::endl;

int T = 15;
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    for (int j = i + 1; j < n; j++)
    {
        if (mass[i] + mass[j] == T)
        {
            std::cout << i << " - " << j << std::endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Это эффективное решение? Оно подойдёт для ста тысяч элементов?

Comment: сто тысяч = 10 ^ 6, а тут явно больше действий. Не пройдет

Answer (score 0):

Неплохую идею предлагали в комментариях - отсортировать массив и идти с двух концов или для каждого элемента осуществлять бин.поиск подходящего. Вроде и вариант идти с двух концов должен зайти, если я не ошибаюсь, ассимптотика будет О(n * log(n)) + O(n), итого примерно 7 * 10 ^6, если 10^6 - макс.входные данные и я умею считать. На всякий случай, если С не нужен, то пропишите `ios_base::sync_with_stdio(0); cin.tie(0); cout.tie(0);` это чутка ускорит ввод-вывод путём отключения синхронизации с С. Также вместо `endl` используйте `/n`.